# How to recite the word "تَأۡمَ۬نَّا" in Surah Yusuf Verse 11 (12:11)?

Tags: quran, tajweed

I have heard that there are two Tareeqs in Hafs 'an Aasim to pronouncing this word. What are those Tareeqs, and how exactly to pronounce it?

Also, what is Ishmam, should it be done at the beginning, middle, or end of the noon in تَأۡمَ۬نَّا, and how long should it be done in the letter (i.e. briefly or throughout the letter)?

Also, is it incorrect to recite the word plainly تَأۡمَنَّا with no special pronounciation?

I couldn't find much clear English information on this online, so I am asking it here in hopes it can be clarified and there is a reference for people.

Comment: Actually the diamond sign in some moshafs show the location of Ishmaam اشمام.

Comment: @Medi1Saif A strange thing I noticed is that there is no sign at all in the Indo-Pak script to indicate anything in that word. Not sure why they would give no indication, when, as I've heard, it is incorrect to pronounce it normally.

Comment: Well the indo-pak moshaf follows specific waqf signs and view. I'm not sure whether these signs include other kind of signs too. The point here is that this تأمنا was a تأمننا but felt to heavy for fluent Arabic speakers. In fact there have been qur'aa who performed it that way, but this recitation is regarded as shadh. As for your question it might be described, but one can't hear the difference rather than see it if one follows the movement of the lips.